# Reformatting a text files output from a list (Java)

Tags: java

I have some code that creates a dictionary (hashmap) and counts the frequency of words in the said document. I then have some code that creates a list of the values in the dictionary and uses the collections.sort() method to sort them, and print out the top 10 to a text file.

My question is how do i change the format of output? currently, the text file is like so:

```
word = 1
word = 2
word = 3
word = 4
word = 5
```

How do i change the formatting and structure of it so i can use the data in future applications? Such as D3?

I've included the code that creates the list and prints it to a text file.

Cheers

```
private static List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortTheHashMap(HashMap<String, Integer> values) throws IOException {

    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = values.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(set);
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
    {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2)
        {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    } );

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:list){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }

    FileWriter fw;
    File fileName;

    fileName = new File("xxx.txt");
    fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> counts : list) {
        fw.write(counts + "\n\n");
        i += 1;
        if (i == 10) {
            break;
        }
    }

    fw.close();

    return list; 
}
```

Comment: How do you want your output? I don't understand your question: You're printing in the file the objects you are in your list, but the fact that they are in a list has nothing to do with the way you print them. Maybe you're searching for Serialization?

Comment: Hi @Ablia, I would like my output to be usable with subsequent applications, such as D3. I want the output to look like a data structure, rather than a list with a '=' separating them. Is it possible to control how the list is printed? Or even print to a JSON format with headers such as 'word' or 'frequency'?

Comment: If you really want JSON, then I would strongly suggest looking into a library such as GSON. JSON can be constructed by hand, but it is much easier to let a library handle the formatting.

Comment: Whilst I really like your answer below and it's simplicity, I'm just thinking wouldn't be hard for D3 distinguish what is what in your method? For example, I may want D3 to calculate the average values and display the words with the highest averages? If I implemented your method without any headings, would D3 recognise what is what?

Comment: Yeah, i think the answer of @KevinO would be far more easier than using JSON. But my point is: D3 can load a text file. So your format should work, but when using the text file in D3 you need to care on how you did the data input, to get the output right and be able to put it in an array. CSV and TSV may be better, dunno, i've never used D3 ^^

Comment: When you use the CSV file in D3, you say how the data is written, so D3 will recognize it. Basically, you say to D3 that the first column is word and the second frequency. Get a look at that: 
[http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this description of what D3 can load](https://www.dashingd3js.com/data-structures-d3js-accepts), you have many options. One of which is a CSV file, so you could change the output to be:

```
fw.write(counts.getKey() + "," + counts.getValue() + "\n");
```

You can replace the "," with a "\t" for a tab separated list also.

Edit: based on a request, here is an approach using `StringBuilder`.

```
int i = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> counts : list) {
    sb.length(0);
    sb.append(counts.getKey());
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(counts.getValue());
    sb.append("\n");
    fw.write(sb.toString());
    i += 1;
    if (i == 10) {
        break;
    }
}
```

You could turn the development of the `String` into a method, so as to reduce the ugliness in the loop. But for basic purposes, it illustrates the point with a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Please use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings with `+` operators. :)

Comment: @KaiserKatze, while I would agree for any large set of data, in this case the output is limited to 10 lines, and it is three fields. I think for clarity of the example, using the concatination is preferable, but I'll add how to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Yeah, the option with concatenation seems more suited. However, is there a way to conclude headers? Or is that something I have to do in D3, or even manually?